# Difficult limit queestion without L'hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I am attempting this limit question here...

> $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}\left(\frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n} -\frac{8^n-4^n+\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n}\right)$

I am supposed to evalute this limit without L'hopital's rule. I'm not really sure how to. The individual limits if I split them just go off to $\infty$ so I can't do that.

I then saw the Sine function so I tried to use the squeeze theorem:

$-1\leq\sin(n)\leq1$

$-1\leq\sin(4^n)\leq1$

$8^n-4^n-1\leq8^n-4^n+\sin(4^n)\leq8^n-4^n+1$

$\frac{8^n-4^n-1}{(-1)^n+4^n}\leq \frac{8^n-4^n+\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n}\leq \frac{8^n-4^n+1}{(-1)^n+4^n}$

$-\frac{8^n-4^n-1}{(-1)^n+4^n}\geq -\frac{8^n-4^n+\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n}\geq -\frac{8^n-4^n+1}{(-1)^n+4^n}$

$-\frac{8^n-4^n+1}{(-1)^n+4^n}\leq -\frac{8^n-4^n+\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n}\leq -\frac{8^n-4^n-1}{(-1)^n+4^n} $

$\frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n}-\frac{8^n-4^n+1}{(-1)^n+4^n}\leq \frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n} -\frac{8^n-4^n+\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n}\leq \frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n}-\frac{8^n-4^n-1}{(-1)^n+4^n} $

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n}-\frac{8^n-4^n+1}{(-1)^n+4^n} \right) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n} -\frac{8^n-4^n+\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n} \right) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n}-\frac{8^n-4^n-1}{(-1)^n+4^n}\right) }$

The problem is that I can't do the limits on the left and right no matter how hard I try. I tried pulling out the highes tpowers, maniputing the powers in different ways to no avail... I know the answer to those limits are $2$ though. I checked.

Again, I can't use L'hopital's rule, Power series, anything like that. I have to use basic calculus 1 techniques.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** Changed $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}}$ to $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}$.

Comment: I assume the limit is as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Yes sorry. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(\frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n} -\frac{8^n-4^n+\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n}\right)=$

$\left(\frac{1+2^{-n}}{5^{-n}+2^{-n}} -\frac{1-2^{-n}+\frac{\sin(4^n)}{8^n}}{\frac{(-1)^n}{8^n}+2^{-n}}\right)$

so

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+2^{-n}}{5^{-n}+2^{-n}} -\frac{1-2^{-n}+\frac{\sin(4^n)}{8^n}}{\frac{(-1)^n}{8^n}+2^{-n}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+2^{-n}}{2^{-n}} -\frac{1-2^{-n}}{2^{-n}}\right)=2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\boxed{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n + 4^n}=0} $$

**prove:**
$$ -1 \le \sin(4^n) \le 1 \\ \frac{-1}{(-1)^n+4^n} \le \frac{\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n} \le \frac{1}{(-1)^n+4^n}$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{-1}{(-1)^n+4^n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{-1}{(-1)^n+4^n} = 0$$
**therfore:**$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n + 4^n}=0$$

---

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}\left(\frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n} -\frac{8^n-4^n+\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n}\right) \\ = \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}\left(\frac{10^n+5^n}{2^n+5^n} -\frac{8^n-4^n}{{(-1)^n+4^n}}-\frac{\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n}\right) \\
\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}\left({\frac{(-10)^n +(-5)^n+2(20)^n-(16)^n+(8)^n}{(2^n+5^n)((-1)^n+4^n)}-\frac{\sin(4^n)}{(-1)^n+4^n}}\right)=+2$$

By divide and multiplying $\frac{1}{20^n}$